# Разница дат PHP

Tags: php, дата

Есть текущая дата, есть некоторая дата, которая берется из базы. Мне нужно найти количество дней между ними, но при попытке сделать это выводит ошибку

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

Собственно, сам код

```
$currdate = date('Y-m-d', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);//текущая дата
$userdate = date('Y-m-d', $user['expire_date']); //дата из базы
$difference = date_diff($currdate, $userdate);
```

При попытке нагуглить выдает примерно тот же код, что и у меня.

Comment: нужно не функцию, а объект new DateTime. Функция возвращает строку, а new DateTime объект.
Если это не содедержит решение (нужно не функцию, а объект new DateTime), то я тада не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$currdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']));
$userdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $user['expire_date']));
$difference = date_diff($currdate, $userdate);
```

Если нужно более точное сравнение то `Y-m-d` меняем на `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
А не подскажете, у меня в качестве разницы выводится 17714 дней. Хотя должно выводить 40. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @ИгорьКуликов покажите `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` и `$user['expire_date']`

Comment: вот - `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] = 2018-07-02, $user['expire_date'] = 2018-08-11 00:00:00`, но я все-равно форматирую под `Y-m-d`